# access variables of one class in another class

Tags: java, android

In my app, I have a class called **Monsters** that reads in data from an XML file. This Monster class calls another class called **MonsterStats**.

*Monster* uses data from the XML file to set variables in the *MonsterStats* class.

Is there a way to use these variables in another class?

Monster.java

```
public class Monster {

public MonsterStats monsterStats;

...processXML pseudo code...
monsterStats.name = xml.monsterName;
monsterStats.type = xml.monsterType;
monsterStats.race = xml.monsterRace;
...etc...
}
```

MonsterStats.java

```
public class MonsterStats {
//encounter info
public String name = "";
public String type = "";
public String race = "";
public String gender = "";
public String alignment = "";   
public int age = 0;

}
```

someOtherClass.java

```
public class someOtherClass {
    //how can I access the variables in MonsterStats
    // that were just set by Monsters???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is skeleton implementation.

```
public class someOtherClass {
    //how can I access the variables in MonsterStats
    // that were just set by Monsters???

Monster mnstr = new Monster();
MonsterStats stats = mnsrt.getMonsterStats();
stats.getName();
............
}

public class Monster {

public MonsterStats monsterStats;

...processXML pseudo code...
monsterStats.name = xml.monsterName;
monsterStats.type = xml.monsterType;
monsterStats.race = xml.monsterRace;
...etc...



public MonsterStats getMonsterStats()
{
.....
return monsterStats;
}

}


public class MonsterStats {
//encounter info
public String name = "";
public String type = "";
public String race = "";
public String gender = "";
public String alignment = "";   
public int age = 0;

public String getName()
{
return name;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what getMonsterStats would do.  Does that just do what the name implies?  So let me get this straight...in someOtherClass, I call Monster...Monster calls MonsterStats, then it processes the XML and sets the variables in MonsterStats. I think I'm getting lost here...

Comment: In getMonsterStats(){  monsterStats.setName(xml.monsterName); ....} Add public void setName(String nameIP) { this.name = nameIP; } etc., in MonstrtStats class.

Comment: It is very simple, MonsterStats is really a getter/setter class (like state holder). In Monster class--getMonsterStats() method, you will parse xml and set those values to monsterStats and return the monsterStats object.

Answer (score 2):

AM I missing something too obvious? How about this?

```
public class someOtherClass {

private MonsterStats stats;

public someOtherClass(MonsterStats stats){
this.stats = stats;
}


public void myMethod(){

//Call this.stats and do what you want. 

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you're in fact mixing up `objects` and `classes`.

I assume that an Object of class `Monster` should be something containing `MonsterStats` and a bit more.

So therefore you just `extend` the MonsterStats-class:

```
public class Monster extends MonsterStats
{
    public Monster(){} 

    public void parseXML()
    {
        //write your MonsterStats for this Monster from xml
    }

    //public String getName()
    //{
    //    return this.name;
    //}
}
```

All the methods you've declared in `MonsterStats` will be useable in the `Monster` class. You can override them if necessary. You do not have to define the `getName()`-method in the Monster class, since you've just extended the `MonsterStats`-class which provides this method.

In your `someOtherClass` you first have to create Objects

```
public class someOtherClass 
{
    Monster myFirstMonster = new Monster();
    myFirstMonster.parseXML();

    String name = myFirstMonster.getName();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I should've said I want each Monster to be its own object...so if I read in a Dragon from the XML file, then I have a Dragon object that I can use anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

It is not this easy. You don't set the variables in the class - to do so, you must declare the variables static - but this is not a good idea (as far as I understand your code).

What you now have is a certain monster (object of class Monster). If you have this object available in an instance of someOtherClass, you can access the things you like.

All in all, I'm under the impression you are mixing classes and objects a little bit.

Can you explain what you want to do with the MonsterStats in someOtherClass?